# How common is it to have multiple muggle-borns in a single family?

Tags: harry-potter

[How common is it to have a Muggle-born in Muggle families in Harry Potter?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/179072/how-common-are-muggle-borns-in-muggle-families-in-harry-potter?noredirect=1&lq=1) covers individual Muggle-Born, but this is about multiple in the same family.

For instance, Collin Creevey introduces himself to Harry as a Muggle-Born in Chamber of Secrets, saying

> "I'm muggle-born, you see. My dad is a milkman. I would love to send a
> picture of us home to them to prove I've met you."

Though I cannot recall the source, I have read that two muggle-borns in the same family are so rare that it is nearly impossible.

Dennis and Collin Creevey, being brothers, are both muggle-born from the same family.

Are they just a rare case or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: The best way to edit a question to add clarity, is to give extra details as part of the existing question and update the title, not to add sections  with "EDIT". See my edit, and please re-[edit] if there's anything amiss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Though I cannot recall the source, I have read that two muggle-borns in the same family are so rare that it is nearly impossible

I’m not sure this is actually stated. On the contrary, we know that Muggleborns [get their magic genetically](https://web.archive.org/web/20080828113728/http://www.bloomsbury.com/harrypotter/default.aspx?sec=3).

> Q: How exactly do muggleborns receive magical ability?

> J.K. Rowling: Muggleborns will have a witch or wizard somewhere on their family tree, in some cases many, many generations back. The gene re-surfaces in some unexpected places.

If Colin has the “gene” its not much of a stretch that his brother would. JK says “in *some cases*” the wizard or witch goes generations back, but there’s really no good reason it couldn’t be a grandparent, in which case the chance of siblings sharing it would be pretty good.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that something else may be at play here. There are no canon-cases of two muggle-born FULLY biological siblings. There are a few ways that situation like that of the
Creevey Brothers can present itself, including but not limited to the following.

### Biological Siblings?

It is possible that they may be step or half brothers, with one being a muggle-born and the other being a half-blood, through a different parent and it is not explicitly mentioned.

### Secrecy?

Like the McGonagall family, it is possible that one of the Creevey brother's parents is a witch/wizard that did effectively hide their power.

### Squibs?

Many times in the wizarding world, Squibs were sent to live in the muggle world. However, they do still carry the magical gene and therefore can have magical children. It could be possible that one of their parents (or both!) was a Squib that still had magical children

### Expulsion?

Sometimes, if a witch/wizard is expelled, they lose their wand, which is snapped, and/or CHOOSES to have their memory wiped (prior to the First Wizarding War, I found this in some JKR interview) It may be that one of their parents faced expulsion and chose to wipe their memory rather than face embarrassment and had magical children, though this seems the most unlikely of all of my thoughts.

Of course, this also could be a plot hole on JKR's part, or they may be that rare case of two muggle-born siblings.

Comment: Is there a reason you've made this answer a community wiki?

Comment: @Valorum just trying to allow people to edit my answer to get the best answer possible. why do you ask?

Comment: Because that's not really what Community Wiki is for

Comment: Right -- anyone can improve your response by editing it at any time! My only wish is that you had written four different answers. That way I can upvote the one I believe to be the best and most likely. Or better, just focus on the *one answer* you believe is most likely and concentrate your efforts on giving the OP the best answer possible!

Comment: @Valorum so what is community wiki for?

Comment: @elemtilas I wasn't sure which was most likely... what do you think about that

Comment: @ava - CW is for answers where you're inviting other people to make significant contributions; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10101/what-are-the-guidelines-for-marking-an-answer-as-community-wiki

Comment: @Valorum that was my point of making it a CW

Comment: @ava - I doubt anyone will add much to a fully fleshed-out answer like this one. It's much more likely they'll just provide their own. CW is more for the *"name all these things"* type questions or *"please give examples of x from every single series of Doctor Who"* sort of thing

Comment: @Valorum oh., sorry about that, was kind of looking for people to kind of elaborate on each individual possibility that may know more about it than me